# Delete action in react redux do not working

Tags: reactjs, redux

I store data in `redux` and I call data from `redux` again, I create actions for delete and update but delete action do not remove that data that stored in state and I do not know if I forgot something or if there is another problem.
And if you can help me with the **update**, thank you

action file:

```
import { todoTypes } from '../constants/actionTypes';

const initialStateTodo = []

export const actions = ((state = initialStateTodo, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case todoTypes.ADD:
        console.log('add todo', action.payload)
        return state.concat(action.payload)

    case todoTypes.DELETE:
        console.log('delete todo', action.payload)
        return state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload)

    case todoTypes.EDIT:
        console.log('update todo', action.payload)
        return state.map((item) => {
            if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    item: action.payload.item
                }
            }
        })
    default:
        return state
   }
})
```

my jsx file:

```
import { Button } from '../partComponents/button'
import { actionCreatores } from '../redux/constants/addTodo'
import 'material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';


export const Todo = () => {

const auto_increment_id = (todos) => {
    const max = todos.reduce((maxId, todo) => Math.max(todo.id, maxId), -1);
    return max + 1
}


const dispatch = useDispatch()
const [todo, setTodo] = useState('');

const selector = useSelector((state) => state.todo)
console.log('selector', selector)

const add = () => {
    if (todo === '') {
        alert('add any value')
    }

    else {
        dispatch(actionCreatores.addTodo({
            id: auto_increment_id(selector),
            item: todo,
            status: 'todo'
        }));
        setTodo('')
    }
}

const handleDelete = (e) => {
    dispatch(actionCreatores.deleteTodo({
        id: e,
        item: todo,
        status: 'todo'
    }));
}

const handleChange = (e) => setTodo(e.target.value);

return (
    <div className="list__addTodo">
        <input
            name='todo'
            type='text'
            className='todo__input'
            placeholder='add todo'
            value={todo}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        />
        <Button
            buttonValue='Submit'
            buttonType='submit'
            buttonClass='todo__btn'
            buttonHandleClick={() => add()}
        />

        <ul className='list__item'>
            {selector.length > 0 && selector.map((item) => {
                return <li className='list__item--value' key={item.id}>{item.item}
                    <span onClick={() => handleDelete(item.id)} class="material-icons list__icon">delete</span>
                    <span class="material-icons list__icon">update</span>
                </li>
            })}
        </ul>
    </div>
)
```

}

Comment: I think you forgot to fetch 'id' while filtering -                                                                
 return state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id)

Comment: yes , thank your are you can help me for update actions???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**id** is missing in filter in delete action:

```
case todoTypes.DELETE:
  console.log('delete todo', action.payload)
  return state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id)
```